# Getting data from jquery created items in controller

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I have created a JSP file and I'm using dynamic inputs created by jQuery. I want to get data from the inputs to the controller. I am using Spring MVC. How can I achieve that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.rollnumberOptions").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).children("option:selected").html();
    $("#selectedItem").append(val + ",");

    var lastField = $("#rollNumberWrapper div:last");
    var intId = (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 1;

    var fieldWrapper;
    var input;
    switch (val) {
      case "CITY_CODE":
        fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
        input = $("<input type=\"hidden\"  style=\"color:black;\" id=\"" + intId + "\" name=\"" + val + "_" + intId + "\" />");
        break;
      case "MODULE_CODE":
        fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
        input = $("<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"color:black;\" id=\"" + intId + "\" name=\"" + val + "_" + intId + "\" />");
        break;
      case "BATCH_CODE":
        fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
        input = $("<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"color:black;\" id=\"" + intId + "\" name=\"" + val + "_" + intId + "\" />");
        break;
      case "USER_SEQUENCE":
        fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
        input = $("<input style=\"color:black;\" type=\"text\" id=\"" + intId + "\" name=\"" + val + "_" + intId + "\" />");
        break;
      case "USER_CONSTANT":
        fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
        input = $("<input style=\"color:black;\" type=\"text\" id=\"" + intId + "\" name=\"" + val + "_" + intId + "\" />");
        break;
    }
    fieldWrapper.append(input);
    $("#inputFieldsDiv").append(fieldWrapper);
  });
});
```

Comment: Put the fields in a `form` and submit it, or send the data in an AJAX request.

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan said, Put the fields in a form. And if you prefer using AJAX request, you can grab all your fields by using `$.serializeArray()` or `$.serialize()` method